# how to convert a csv file to json in the format below on python

Tags: python, csv

I would like to convert a csv to Json in the format below:

```
{  cols: [   {id: "DATA", label: "DATA", type: "date"},   {id: "test1", label: "test1", type: "number"},    {id: "test2", label: "test2", type: "number"},    {id: "test3", label: "test3", type: "number"},    .    .    .   ],   rows: [    {c: [      {v: new Date(2019,7,1), f: "2019-07-01"},     {v: 14111},     {v: null},     {v: null},     .     .     .    ]} }
```

It's possible?

Comment: where is the csv ?(show the sample data). also if you could format the json (pretty looking json) it will be easy to interpret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Afternoon Aditya Singh,

So what I want is to transform a csv from the pattern below:

```
         DATA_CRIACAO;PROMOCAO_1067;PROMOCAO_1068 
         01/07/0019;14217; 
         01/07/0019;;24
```

to Json in the format below:

> 

```
       { 
         cols: [ 
                 {id: "DATA_CRIACAO", label: "DATA_CRIACAO", type: "date"}, 
                 {id: "PROMOCAO_1067", label: "PROMOCAO_1067", type: "number"}, 
                 {id: "PROMOCAO_1068", label: "PROMOCAO_1068", type: "number"} 
               ], 
         rows: [ 
                 {c: [ {v: new Date(2019,7,1), f: "2019-07-01"}, {v: 14111}, {v: null} ]} 
                 {c: [ {v: new Date(2019,7,1), f: "2019-07-01"}, {v: null}, {v: 24} ]} 
               ]
        }
```

What I wanted is to create a structure in Json in the pattern above.